# "The developer buy flow has been deprecated"

Tags: ios, facebook, ads

I have an iOS app that has the Facebook SDK integrated and I have been running Pay Per Install campaigns from Facebook.

Recently tried to set this up for another app with the same SDK but then I got this error: "The developer buy flow has been deprecated" right after I set up the Facebook app and clicked on Promote.

Is this a bug or did Facebook change something with their process?

Any insights are welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

They deprecated the developer buy flow and integrated it into "Advertise on Facebook"->"App Installs"
https://www.facebook.com/ads/create/